# Найти все пути между двумя вершинами графа

Tags: c++

Нужно найти все пути между любыми двумя вершинами графа. Непонятно, как это сделать.

Comment: никак. Их количество может быть порядка факториала от вершин.

Comment: @pavel: Но это не отменяет потенциальной возможности? Если, конечно, нет циклов.

Comment: @VladD ну тогда рекурсия и вперёд)

Comment: @pavel: BFS скорее?

Comment: @VladD Тогда это модифицированный BFS, который посещает уже посещенные вершины...

Comment: @Harry: Ну, бесконечный, который не останавливается на первом нахождении, да.

Comment: @VladD просто я обычно предполагаю что автор может написать решение в лоб типо перебор всех путей за  факториал и проверка что там ребро есть. И говорю что глобально лучше не будет, только отсечения.

Comment: Подумалось... а точно пути? Случайно не расстояния между всеми вершинами? :)

Comment: @pavel: Ну, мне кажется, такие вещи всё же стоит объяснять поподробнее людям без олимпиадного опыта.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Исходник](http://forum.algolist.ru/algorithm-graph/1044-poisk-putei-v-grafe.html) - плохо искали, если не нашли

Ну так а это решается просто динамическим программированием. Пусть s и t - начальная и конечная вершины. Для начала удалите из графа все вершины, недостижимые из s, и все вершины, из которых нельзя достичь t. Топологически отсортируйте граф. Если он содержит цикл (что эквивалентно отсутствию топ. сортировки), то число путей бесконечно - можно все время ходить по циклу.

После топологической сортировки, вершины графа будут перенумерованы числами от 1 до N, так, что вершина s получит номер 1 (т.к. из нее достижимы все вершины), а вершина t -- номер N, и при это все ребра ориентированы от вершины с меньшим номером к вершине с большим номеров (по определению топ. сортировки).

Заведем массив `a[1..N]`, такой что элемент `a[x]` содержит число путей от `x` до `t`, и рассчитаем его содержимое, по формулам:
`a[N] = 1`.
Для `x < N`: `a[x]` = сумма `a[y]` для всех `y`, таких что существует ребро `(x, y)`.
После этого `a[1]` будет ответом.

Comment: В смысле "удалите из графа все вершины, недостижимые из s, и все вершины, из которых нельзя достичь t". Если удалять каждую вершину, которая не инцидентна s и t, то в общем случае мы получим 2 не связных подграфа. Или я что-то не понял?

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg Из удаленных вершин никакого пути не может существовать...

Comment: В смысле? Если я удалю все вершины, которые не инцидентны вершинам начала и конца, то я потеряю все пути

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg Ну, если вы не можете из вершины a достичь b, то зачем вам a

Comment: Но если мы из вержины a можем достичь вершину c, из которой может достичь вершину b, то нам ее удалять нельзя, а при данном алгоритме мы ее удалим

Comment: @sm4ll_3gg Нет, если нужно найти путь между a и b, а вершина с лежит между ними, мы её не удалим(т.к из с тоже можна достичь b). Если из с мы не сможем достичь её, тогда она удалится.