# Как найти все возможные пути от указанной до указанной точки?

Tags: php, алгоритм

Есть такой массив:

```
[
  0 => [56,53],
  1 => [54,43],
  2 => [43,53],
  3 => [53,56],
  4 => [53,55],
  5 => [53,54],
  6 => [50,53],
  7 => [60,43],
  8 => [53,59],
  9 => [53,43],
  10 => [56,54],
  11 => [55,53],
  12 => [54,53],
  13 => [53,60],
  14 => [61,60],
];
```

Он показывает точки движения на графе. Из точки 56 можно перейти в 53, из 54 в 43, из 53 в 56 и т.д.

Как найти все возможные пути из точки А в Б? Например из 53 в 43. Предположим, что это будет:

```
53->43
53->54->43
53->60->61->43
```

Вроде умом понимаю, что надо то ли поиск в ширину, то ли поиск в глубину использовать, но что-то не понимаю как это сделать. Может быть подскажите алгоритм чуть более детальный, что делать, нежели направить на алгоритм поиска в глубину?))

Comment: А если в графе будет цикл? Связанный вопрос: [Найти все пути между двумя вершинами графа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/604075).

Comment: Также может быть полезно: [Задача о кратчайшем пути](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B8).

Comment: В приведенном примере есть циклы.

Comment: Возможно имелись ввиду только простые пути.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/925076/

Comment: а чего там направлять то, запускайте поиск в глубину пока до нужной вершины не дойдете, вершины только помечайте, чтобы повторно в них не заходить

Comment: @teran да, кажется я сделал) стоило мозг проветрить)